Getting Segmentation Fault in my code and can't seem to get why
I am writing a program that reads and decodes IEEE-754 single-precision floating-point numbers. The program is supposed to continue processing numbers until the user inputs zero. For each number, it will decode and display the number in scientific notation, compute and display the square, and, if applicable, compute and display the square root. However at the moment I am getting Segmentation Fault, unless I input 0 in which the code exits with exit code 0.
So this is the code that I am using
        .data
prompt:         .asciz "\nEnter the single precision floating point value (0 to exit): "
initValMsg:     .asciz "The initial value is:     "
squareMsg:      .asciz "The value squared is:     "
rootMsg:        .asciz "The root of the value is: "
newline:        .asciz "\n"
scanfFormat:    .asciz "%f"
printfFormat:   .asciz "%d"
plusChar:       .byte '+', 0
minusChar:      .byte '-', 0
oneDot:         .asciz "1."
expChar:        .asciz " E"

        .text
        .global main

main:
        STMDB   SP!, {R4, LR}

main_loop:
        LDR     R0, =prompt
        BL      printf

        SUB     SP, SP, #8
        MOV     R1, SP
        LDR     R0, =scanfFormat
        BL      scanf

        LDR     R0, [SP]
        ADD     SP, SP, #8

        CMP     R0, #0
        BEQ     end_program

        MOV     R4, R0

        LDR     R0, =initValMsg
        BL      printf

        MOV     R0, R4
        BL      decode_and_display

        VMOV    S0, R4
        VMUL.F32 S0, S0, S0
        VMOV    R0, S0

        LDR     R0, =squareMsg
        BL      printf

        BL      decode_and_display

        MOVS    R4, R4
        BMI     skip_sqrt

        VMOV    S0, R4
        VSQRT.F32 S0, S0
        VMOV    R0, S0

        LDR     R0, =rootMsg
        BL      printf

        BL      decode_and_display

skip_sqrt:
        B       main_loop

end_program:
        LDMIA   SP!, {R4, LR}
        MOV     R0, #0
        BX      LR

decode_and_display:
        STMDB   SP!, {R4-R6, LR}

        MOV     R4, R0

        MOVS    R4, R4
        BPL     positive_sign
        LDR     R0, =minusChar
        BL      printf
        B       print_mantissa
positive_sign:
        LDR     R0, =plusChar
        BL      printf

print_mantissa:
        LDR     R0, =oneDot
        BL      printf

        MOV     R5, R4, LSL #1
        MOV     R5, R5, LSR #24
        SUB     R5, R5, #127

        MOV     R6, R4, LSL #9

        MOV     R2, #23

print_mantissa_loop:
        CMP     R2, #0
        BEQ     print_exponent

        MOVS    R6, R6, LSL #1
        BPL     mantissa_bit_zero
        MOV     R0, #'1'
        BL      putchar
        B       mantissa_next_bit
mantissa_bit_zero:
        MOV     R0, #'0'
        BL      putchar
mantissa_next_bit:
        SUB     R2, R2, #1
        B       print_mantissa_loop

print_exponent:
        LDR     R0, =expChar
        BL      printf

        MOV     R0, R5
        LDR     R1, =printfFormat
        BL      printf

        LDR     R0, =newline
        BL      printf

        LDMIA   SP!, {R4-R6, LR}
        BX      LR

I am not trying to change the code too much, and using PUSH, POP, Conditional Execution and using VLDMIA/VSTMDB or STMFD/LDMFD is a no go. I think I might have messed something up when saving/restoring but I am not sure.

Where does the segfault occur, and what are the contents of relevant registers and memory at that point? Your debugger can tell you that, as well as letting you single step to see what happens leading up to the crash.

        MOV     R0, R5
        LDR     R1, =printfFormat
        BL      printf

You have reversed the arguments to printf.  It's trying to use the integer in R0 as the pointer to the format string, which is likely to segfault.
